# pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

this is my model for LinearRegression of salary pridict for pratcit but gating a error `pl.plot(x_train, model.predict(x_train))`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
x = df[['YearsExperience']]
y = df['Salary']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)

model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train,y_train)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pl = plt
pl.scatter(x_train, y_train)
pl.plot(x_train, model.predict(x_train))
pl.show()
```

this is data iam using

```
YearsExperience,Salary
1.1,39343.00
1.3,46205.00
1.5,37731.00
2.0,43525.00
2.2,39891.00
2.9,56642.00
3.0,60150.00
3.2,54445.00
3.2,64445.00
3.7,57189.00
3.9,63218.00
4.0,55794.00
4.0,56957.00
4.1,57081.00
4.5,61111.00
4.9,67938.00
5.1,66029.00
5.3,83088.00
5.9,81363.00
6.0,93940.00
6.8,91738.00
7.1,98273.00
7.9,101302.00
8.2,113812.00
8.7,109431.00
9.0,105582.00
9.5,116969.00
9.6,112635.00
10.3,122391.00
10.5,121872.00
```

this is error iam fasing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc      
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 142, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc      
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Project\data scince\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    pl.plot(x_train, model.predict(x_train))
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2757, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1632, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 312, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 487, in _plot_args
    x = _check_1d(xy[0])
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1327, in _check_1d
    ndim = x[:, None].ndim
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3628, in get_loc
    self._check_indexing_error(key)
  File "D:\Softwers\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5637, in _check_indexing_error
    raise InvalidIndexError(key)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a Series as `x-axis` not a DataFrame:

```
pl.plot(x_train['YearsExperience'], model.predict(x_train))

# OR

pl.plot(x_train.squeeze(), model.predict(x_train))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with the exact same error reported: `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key`. I also solved it by using `df.iloc[:, :-1].values` instead on `df.iloc[:, :-1]` in  `plot`. For me the problem appears only on one computer but not on another, with different matplotlib and/or pandas versions, which might be the root cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

this is solving my problem dont known why?

```
x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values
```

thats full code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)

model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train,y_train)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pl = plt
pl.scatter(x_train, y_train)
pl.plot(x_train, model.predict(x_train))
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I think you should change it to a numpy array.

ex: pl.scatter(x_train.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).